# Why does my Kotlin Gradle build die with exit code 137?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

We were seeing mysterious failures in our CI environment when running tests of a Kotlin code base.

`gradle test` compiled the code and the tests just fine. The tests ran and all appeared to pass. But then Gradle exited with code 137 (indicating it was killed with SIGKILL) and the CI system thus thought the build had failed.

Limiting the size of the JVM for Gradle didn't help. Nor did the `--no-daemon` and `--max-workers` options.

This is using Kotlin 1.2.40 and Gradle 4.3 on the Java 8 JVM.

Answer (score 7):

The culprit in this case turned out to be the Kotlin compiler.

By default, the Kotlin compiler spawns a daemon in the background so that subsequent compilation jobs are faster. For a Kotlin code base of nontrivial size, this process can end up eating significant memory.

Its presence was causing Gradle to hit the memory limit on the CI container, and the [Linux OOM killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) was killing the Gradle process.

The solution: [Tell the Kotlin compiler not to spawn the background process.](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/solved-disable-kotlin-compiler-process-keepalive/2622) This turns out to be a simple matter of setting an environment variable:

`GRADLE_OPTS=-Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process`

With that variable in place, Kotlin compilation runs inline in the Gradle JVM, and its data can thus be garbage-collected when Gradle moves on to running the tests.

It would also work to pass the option to the `gradle` command rather than setting it in the environment.

Comment: I talked to the gradle team.  They recommend using the default daemon.  Basically the kotlin compiler will run in its own daemon, which saves it a bunch of a time via warmup specific for the kotlin compiler.  You can increase the compiler daemon's memory using -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx6g.  

Article below
https://dev.to/martinhaeusler/is-your-kotlin-compiler-slow-here-s-a-potential-fix-4if4